# CSS - @container is not working even though it is suppose to be supported in Chrome 109

Tags: css

I am currently running Chrome version 109 and on caniuse.com it says that the `@container` query is supported. Despite of this I cannot get it to work. Am I using it wrong? Are any of you getting it to work in your browsers?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
}
.col2 {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 150px;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@container (max-width: 150px) {
  .grid {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col1'>1</div>
  <div class='col2'>2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm writing here in English using an online translator. Possible mental errors in perception. I meant that the container type must be specified on the parent element. For example, like this:

```css
.grid { 
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; 
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden; 
    container-type: inline-size; 
} 
.col1 { 
    background-color: #ccc; 
    height: 150px; 
} 
.col2 {
    background-color: #eee; 
    height: 150px; 
    /* container-type: inline-size;  */
}
@container (min-width: 150px) { 
    .col1 { background-color: red; } 
}
```

Comment: I made this change, and it still does not work

Comment: Strange. Give me your code, please.

Comment: I used the same code as you wrote. Is it working for you in Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes. Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official build), (64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

@Oscar R, @Maxim has given you the right answer below, so you should give him the solution acceptance. @Maxim, you translation there is very clear; don't concern :)

I suspect what's the matter with your code after his replacement is that you haven't enclosed the CSS in a `<style></style>` element. So it's not being seen for purpose.

It will also help if you color the basis columns in something other than white...I've given a full example, running here at the moment and working fine on Chrome and Firefox.

A couple of extra observations from running it...on an even later version of Chrome, 110, the smaller screens emulation (phones, etc.) is broken as yet for container queries; it won't work to reduce screen width that way. Instead, you can either collapse your browser width, or maybe more conenient, ctrl-shift-I to get the debug panel, then pull its left edge over to reduce available screen.

On Firefox, the phone/pad emulation works fine, and you can flip one on its side to switch column size and thus color.

And one more thing I found to interfere with container queries is an extension which gives controllable dark mode that I use, Dark Reader. This is very likely because it emits its own css not well combined with yours. With such extensions, you won't see the container query operating.

```
<style>
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
    container-type: inline-size;
  }

  .col1 {
    background-color: #117486;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .col2 {
    background-color: #e88500;
    height: 150px;
    /* container-type: inline-size;  */
  }

  @container (min-width: 750px) {
    .col1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col1'>1</div>
  <div class='col2'>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: p.s. if you're reading this by email, I've edited in more information after the initial posting it would give you, so you can have a look at the web Stackoverflow...